# Data table not working and not filter data

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I have used data table code, but where I used search filter table getting code error.

```
if($("#newuser").length != 0) {

   var oTable = $("#newuser").DataTable({

        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,  
        "ajax": {
            "url": base_url+'users/listing',
            "type": "POST", 
        }, 
        "columnDefs": [{ orderable: false, targets: [0]  }],
        "order": [[6, "desc" ]], 
    });

    $('#newuser').on( 'draw.dt', function () {
        $('[data-plugin="switchery"]').each(function (idx, obj) {
            new Switchery($(this)[0], $(this).data());
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this part

```
"url": base_url+'users/listing',
```

into this

```
"url": "<?php echo base_url('users/listing'); ?>",
```

***do not forget that base_url is from PHP